# jarsigner use to verify a signed apk and error message "java.lang.SecurityException invalid SHA1 signature file digest ..."

Tags: android, keytool, gluon-mobile, jarsigner, javafxports

I used the keytool command (from jdk 1.8) for generating the keystore and its first certificate dedicated to an application "toto".

After generating the signed .apk file with jarsigner (from jdk 1.8, too) with this command:
jarsigner -keystore toto.jks -storepass pw1 -signedJar titi_signed.apk titi.apk aliasPlus,
**I executed the jarsigner for verifying it (with jarsigner -verify** ...).

And, I got this problem :

***java.lang.SecurityException invalid SHA1 signature file digest for com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/capian/left-btn.png***

By searching this error message in google, there is ony one result:
https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/secure/ReleaseNote.jspa?projectId=10100&version=11815

So, is it a JDK bug?

Thanks

Note: the initial question was about the portecle use. Thanks to Nick for the response. That's why I gave up the portecle use for coming back to the fundamental DOS command "keytool"

Comment: The Android Developer documentation has a good explanation of how to build an APK. Have a look there. https://developer.android.com/studio/run/

Comment: I don't use the "classical" Android environment but JavaFX under Eclipse, with Gluon. In ths context, how to do easily (jarsigner command, gradle, ...)?

Comment: Everything these days for working with Android is with Android Studio and/or gradle. Eclipse support was dropped a long time ago. I would recommend you install gradle if you are unable to port your project to Android Studio format. Good luck with this.

Comment: Richard, it is not the object of my question:)

Comment: Android Studio does not allow to generate an application for Windows. That's why I did not use it: my product is dedicated to Android AND Windows (and iOS in the future).

Comment: Got it. Good luck then

Answer (score 0):

I've never used portecle. And given that nearly every serious open source project has migrated off sourceforge to github or similar, I'd be nervous of using any security tool I found there. But on [their website](http://portecle.sourceforge.net/) they have this screenshot:

[image: Portecle screenshot]

Which at the top shows "/tmp/cacerts" as the path. Which makes me think in this case the directory things are stored in is /tmp/cacerts.

So if you create a keystore, it is probably wherever you chose to save it to using the file menu.